# Where can I add u-boot commands to get executed when Beagle Bone Black boots from eMMC

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I need to load a device tree overlay when the Beagle Bone Black boots by executing u-boot commands when the board starts up.

However, all commands that I add to the /boot/uEnv.txt file don't get executed.

I tried adding a debug message to /boot/uEnv.txt to check if these commands get executed but nothing gets displayed on the boot terminal.

I would like to execute these commands in u-boot when the Beagle Bone Black boots from the eMMC.

```
setenv fdtaddr 0x87f00000
setenv fdtovaddr 0x87fc0000
load mmc 1:1 ${fdtaddr} /boot/dtbs/4.14.71-ti-r80/am355x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dtb
load mmc 1:1 ${fdrovaddr} /lib/firmware/PCDEV0.dtbo
fdt addr $fdtaddr
fdt resize 8192
fdt apply $fdtovaddr
```

Where can I add these commands to get executed on boot.

Thank You

Comment: Did you read any [documentation](https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? "*However, all commands that I add ...*" -- You don't "*add commands*" to the environment; it's not a shell script. You define environment variables for the environment. There is only one variable that is guaranteed to be auto-executed, which is `bootcmd`. You can have a variable contain more than one command by using a semicolon, `;`. For a complex example from a recent question I answered, see https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/f07e3d2d83c0f311bdebbf4c12646df8

Comment: `fdt resize 8192` -- Have you actually tested this command? FYI all numeric values to U-Boot are interpreted as hexadecimal values, regardless of whether there's a `0x` prefix or not. There is no method for entering decimal values.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I saw that there is commented out text in the uEnv.txt with commands to add overlays. When I added the path to my overlay in there and uncommented the line, it worked.